# Table: colored row not aligned with toprule

Tags: tables, color

I am creating a table with colored rows. The problem is that the colored strip is not aligned with the top rule, as shown in figure. How can I solve it? Thank you.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\usepackage[first=0,last=9]{lcg}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rand0.\arabic{rand}}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Me}
%\date{10 dicembre 2015}

\maketitle

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{} lrr @{}}
\toprule
 & \textbf{GE90} & \textbf{PW4000-100}\\
\midrule
\rowcolor{LightCyan}
\textbf{Company} & General Electric & Pratt \& Whitney\\
\textbf{Velivolo} & Boeing 777 & Airbus A330\\
\rowcolor{LightCyan}
\textbf{Pressure ratio} & 37.8 & 32.0 \\
\textbf{BPR} & 8.4 & 5.0\\
\rowcolor{LightCyan}
\textbf{Spinta al Take-off} (N) & 375300 & 286910\\
\textbf{Spinta al cruise} (N) & 69200 & 78071\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Caratteristiche della piastra e del canale}
\label{tab:dati_canale-piastra}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`\rowcolor` has two optional arguments (after the color name), the first optional argument has the left overhang, the 2nd one stands for the right overhang. As far as I know, the overhang defaults to `6pt`.

If the left overhang should be killed, use `[0pt]`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\usepackage[first=0,last=9]{lcg}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rand0.\arabic{rand}}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Me}
%\date{10 dicembre 2015}

\maketitle

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{} lrr @{}}
\toprule
 & \textbf{GE90} & \textbf{PW4000-100}\\
\midrule
\rowcolor{green}[0pt]
\textbf{Company} & General Electric & Pratt \& Whitney\\
\textbf{Velivolo} & Boeing 777 & Airbus A330\\
\rowcolor{green}[0pt]
\textbf{Pressure ratio} & 37.8 & 32.0 \\
\textbf{BPR} & 8.4 & 5.0\\
\rowcolor{green}[0pt]
\textbf{Spinta al Take-off} (N) & 375300 & 286910\\
\textbf{Spinta al cruise} (N) & 69200 & 78071\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Caratteristiche della piastra e del canale}
\label{tab:dati_canale-piastra}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I changed the color to make it more outstanding (only for this screenshot). I would not recommend it for the real document of course

Comment: To my taste is such cases better not use `@{}` on begin  and end of table option field. Result is nicer and aligning of colored rows with others is correct. However, tastes are different :-)

Comment: @Zarko: I agree, but at the moment I leave it as it is. You can of course provide another (better!) solution!

Answer (score 2):

This is not better solution as provided Christian Hupfer, actually, as question indicate problem with MWE, it is only possible. However, use of `@{}` on begin and on end table columns is usual last (desperate)  measure to fit table in text width. As can be concluded from given MWE, this is not a case, so the both `@{}` can be omitted. By this the problem of protrusion of colored rows out of table disappear:

[image]

```
    \begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l r r}
    \toprule
                            & \textbf{GE90}     & \textbf{PW4000-100}\\
    \hline%midrule
    \rowcolor{green}
Company                     & General Electric  & Pratt \& Whitney\\
Velivolo                    & Boeing 777 & Airbus A330\\
    \rowcolor{green}
Pressure ratio              & 37.8              & 32.0 \\
BPR & 8.4 & 5.0\\
    \rowcolor{green}
Spinta al Take-off $(N)$    & 375300            & 286910\\
Spinta al cruise $(N)$      & 69200             & 78071\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (and its built-in command `\rowcolors`), you have directly the expected output.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{} lrr @{}}[color-inside]
\toprule
 & \textbf{GE90} & \textbf{PW4000-100}\\
\midrule
\rowcolors{LightCyan}{}  % \rowcolors is built-in in {NiceTabular}
\textbf{Company} & General Electric & Pratt \& Whitney\\
\textbf{Velivolo} & Boeing 777 & Airbus A330\\
\textbf{Pressure ratio} & 37.8 & 32.0 \\
\textbf{BPR} & 8.4 & 5.0\\
\textbf{Spinta al Take-off} (N) & 375300 & 286910\\
\textbf{Spinta al cruise} (N) & 69200 & 78071\\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\captionof{table}{Caratteristiche della piastra e del canale}
\label{tab:dati_canale-piastra}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

However, you need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/TikZ nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]